# Spectrogram to ArrayPlot

Tags: plotting, sound

I have an `Audio` that I want to extract the `Spectrogram` data from such that when I plot it using `ArrayPlot` it looks the same as the `Spectrogram` (I reversed it and then 1 minus to make it look exactly the same). It was working when I retrieved it from `Spectrogram[audio][[1,1,All,All,1]]`, but after a Mathematica crash it no longer outputs the same matrix with the same audio. It used to be something like 512x954 but now its 256x5080.

EDIT: Turns out that changing the `partition` and `offset` parameters changes the dimensions of the matrix. With default values it reverts to 512x954 but with `partition=512` and `offset=64` it becomes 256x5080. But when I `ArrayPlot` the matrix from the default parameters it looks the same as the `Spectrogram`, this however doesn't happen for other values of the parameters. Is there a way to reconstruct the spectogram with `Arrayplot` for non-default values of `partition` and `offset'`?

CODE:

```
Export["sound.wav", Play[(2 + Cos[50 t])*Sin[2000*(1 + Round[2 t, 0.1])* t] , {t, 0, 1}]]
audio = Import["sound.wav"]
spec = Spectrogram[audio, ColorFunction -> GrayLevel]
ArrayPlot[1 - Reverse@spec[[1, 1, All, All, 1]]]
```

produces an `ArrayPlot` that looks like `spec`, but changing `spec` to `spec = Spectrogram[audio, 2048, 32, BlackmanHarrisWindow]` produces an `ArrayPlot` that does not look like `spec`.

Comment: So you just want to re-create the output of `Spectrogram` using `ArrayPlot`?

Comment: Technically, I want the matrix that represents the `Spectrogram` data and I use an `ArrayPlot` to verify that they are the same. But short answer is yes.

Comment: Instead of using that unreadable [`Part`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) expression use [`SpectrogramArray`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SpectrogramArray.html) and [`Transpose`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html).

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific. I have tried using `SpectrogramArray`. I know I can remove half of the array because the amplitudes are mirrored but then I'm stumped. I'm not that familiar with DSP or STFT but I just want the data to play with. Is `SpectrogramArray` outputted as Freq. x Time or some other dimensions? (I used `Re` on the whole array just so I could plot it to see what the data looked like. I don't know what the imaginary component is supposed to represent)

Comment: The [documentation for Spectrogram](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Spectrogram.html) shows how to create a spectrogram from `SpectrogramArray` (see the Properties & Relations section)

Comment: Thanks for that. Is there any reason why the spectrogram output from `Spectrogram[]` and converting `SpectogramArray[]` to a spectrogram look different (not just the colors scheme)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you just want to verify it,so you can try `SpectrogramArray`

```
spec = Spectrogram[audio, 2048, 32, BlackmanHarrisWindow, 
    ColorFunction -> GrayLevel, Frame -> None, ImageSize -> Medium];
data = SpectrogramArray[audio, 2048, 32, BlackmanHarrisWindow];

ImageResize[ImageCrop@ArrayPlot[1 - Reverse@spec[[1, 1, All, All, 1]], 
        Frame -> None], ImageDimensions@spec]
ImageAdjust@ImageResize[Image[Reverse@Transpose@Abs[data[[All, 1 ;; Dimensions[data][[2]]/2]]]], 
        ImageDimensions@spec]
ImageResize[ImageCrop@spec, ImageDimensions@spec]
```

[image]

exactly the same.